# JPA Specification Select returns all columns instead of specific

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I am using JPA Specification , need to select specific columns only.

This is the code:

```
       Specification<Item> spec = (root, query, builder) -> {
            query.select(root.get("Id"));

            Predicate predicate = builder.equal(root.get("Id"), "12345");

            return predicate;

        };
```

In log I see that all columns from Item `Entity` are selected from database.

Is it a bug?

usage:

interface:

```
public interface Repo extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Item,String>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Item> {
}
```

call:

```
repo.findAll(spec );
```

Comment: Can you show us how you are using this Specification?

Comment: added code to the post

Answer (score 0):

`JpaSpecificationExecutor` is specifically defined to return the entity type. I suspect it is ignoring the `.select(root.get("Id"))`.

Normally you would use Specifications if you have an extremely dynamic set of conditions you are querying by. If you have just a few parameters you need to search by, I would use a derived query, or a named query.

```
public interface Repo extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Item,String>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Item> {

   @Query("Select i.id from Item i where name=:name")
   Long getIdforName(String name);
}
```

Comment: I have complex dynamic where clause that I omitted from question (I thought its not important).I construct it in the spec.